# Python regex split but retain certain characters for split

Tags: regex, python-3.x, split

I have the following text

```
text = "Perennials. Stolons slender. Perianth bristles 6 or 7, ca. 2 × as long as nutlet"
```

I want to split the passage using the separate defined as ".\s[A-Z]". However, I still wish to retain the [A-Z] within the original sentence, such that the output is this:

```
['Perennials',
 'Stolons slender',
 'Perianth bristles 6 or 7, ca. 2 × as long as nutlet']
```

So far I have done is:

```
re.split(r'\.\s[A-Z]', text)
```

but it removed the first alphabets:

```
['Perennials',
 'tolons slender',
 'erianth bristles 6 or 7, ca. 2 × as long as nutlet']
```

Can anyone help? Thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split using a lookahead:

```
result = re.split(r'\.\s(?=[A-Z])', text)
print(result)

['Perennials', 'Stolons slender', 'Perianth bristles 6 or 7, ca. 2 × as long as nutlet']
```

The lookahead `(?=[A-Z])` will assert, but not consume, that what follows the dot and space is a capital letter.

Comment: ok thats fast, I was still trying to find the edit button to change the title!